# Scraping webpage with Python: how to return a list of titles of certain elements?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I had luck getting a list of telephone numbers using this code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

lnk='https://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/2019/legislators/assembly'
page=requests.get(lnk)
tree=html.fromstring(page.content)

ph_nums=tree.xpath('//span[@class="info telephone"]/text()')
print(ph_nums)
```

which is scraping info from an HTML element that looks like this:

```
<span class="info telephone">
      <span class="title"><strong>Telephone</strong>:<br></span>
      (608) 266-8580<br>(888) 534-0097
  </span>
```

However, I can't do the same for this element when I change `info telephone` to `info`...

```
<span class="info" style="width:16em;">
  <span>
        <a id="A">
    <strong></strong></a><strong><a href="http://legis.wisconsin.gov/assembly/97/allen">Jenkins, Leroy t</a></strong> <small>(R - Madison)</small>
          </span>

  <br>

  <span style="width:8em;"><small>District 69</small></span>

  <br>

  <span style="width:8em;"><a href="/2019/legislators/assembly/1891">Details</a></span>

  <br>

  <span style="width:8em;">
      <a href="http://legis.wisconsin.gov/assembly/97/allen">   Website</a>
  </span>

  <br>

      <br>

</span>
```

since there's multiple titles in this element, whereas "info telephone" only had one. How would I return separate lists, each with a different piece of info (i.e. a list of names, and a list of Districts, in this scenario)?

FYI - I am not educated in HTML (and hardly experienced in Python) so I would appreciate a simplified explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For this task I would recommend the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) Package for Python.

You don't have to deeply understand HTML to use it (I don't!), and it offers a very friendly approach to find certain items from a web page.

Your first example could be rewritten as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#soup element contains the xml data
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml') 
# the find_all method finds all nodes in page.content whose type is 'span' 
# and whose class is 'info telephone'
info_tels = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "info telephone"})
```

The `info_tels` element contains all instances of `<span class="info telephone">` on your document. We can then parse it to find what's relevant:

```
list_tels = []
for tel in info_tels:
    tel_text = tel.text #extracts text from info_telephone node
    tel_text = tel_text.replace("\nTelephone:\n","").replace('\n', "") #removes "Telephone:" part and line breaks
    tel_text = tel_text.strip() #removes trailing space
    list_tels.append(tel_text)
```

You can do something similar for the 'info' class:

```
info_class = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "info"})
```

And then find the elements you want to put into lists:

```
info_class[0].find_all('a')[1].text #returns you the first name
```

The challenge here is to identify which types/classes do these names/districts/etc. have. In your first example, it is relatively clear (('span', {"class": "info telephone"})), but the "info" class has various data points inside of it with no specific, identifiable type.

For instance, the '' tag appears multiple times in your file, also with distinct data points (District, Details, etc.)

I came up with a small solution for the District problem - you might get inspired to tackle the other information too!!

```
list_districts = []
for info in info_class:
    try:
       district_contenders = info.find_all('span', {'style': "width:8em;"})
        for element in district_contenders:
            if 'District' in element.text:
                list_districts.append(element.text)
    except: 
        pass
```